# How do I fetch data from database in real time (vuejs)?

Tags: database, web, vue.js, real-time

At the moment i want to make a public kanban board. So f.e friends can add new Cards or edit Cards. Because of that i need sth to update the content in real time. So after a change in the database, the content will update for all users aswell without reloading the page.

It would be nice if you tell me, what should i do/use,etc. to fetch data from database in real time in my laravel project (vuejs).

Comment: Realtime? sounds like you want to use websockets

Comment: Hi vace, welcome to Stackoverflow. Your question is currently very broad and that makes it very hard to answer properly. When do you want to retrieve (or send) data? How much data do you want to send? Do you have a REST api?

Comment: @Sumurai8 At the moment i want to make a public kanban board. So f.e friends can add new Cards or edit Cards. Because of that i need sth to update the content in real time. So after a change in the database, the content will update for all users aswell without reloading the page.

Comment: Yes, go ahead and add that to your question, as well as more context.  Do you have a vuex store yet?  Or do you want a simpler solution with just vue.js and service functions?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can use websocket in your backend and listen for changes in frontend vuejs.